# $2$-dimensional adjunctions via pre/post-composition

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, 2-categories

Recall that in the setting of $1$-categories, given functors $L\colon\mathcal{C}\longrightarrow\mathcal{D}$ and $R\colon\mathcal{D}\longrightarrow\mathcal{C}$, the following conditions are equivalent:

1. We have an adjunction $L\dashv R\colon \mathcal{C}\rightleftarrows\mathcal{D}$;
2. For each category $\mathcal{K}$, we have an adjunction $L_*\dashv R_*\colon\mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{K},\mathcal{C})\rightleftarrows\mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{K},\mathcal{D})$, i.e. a natural bijection
   $$
   \mathrm{Nat}(L\circ F,G)
   \cong
   \mathrm{Nat}(F,R\circ G).
   $$
3. For each category $\mathcal{E}$, we have an adjunction $R^*\dashv L^*\colon\mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{E})\rightleftarrows\mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{D},\mathcal{E})$, i.e. a natural bijection
   $$
   \mathrm{Nat}(F\circ R,G)
   \cong
   \mathrm{Nat}(F,G\circ L).
   $$

Passing now to bicategories, the situation gets more complicated: in place of $\mathrm{Nat}$, we have $\mathsf{LaxNat}$, $\mathsf{OplaxNat}$, $\mathsf{PseudoNat}$, and, if $F$ and $G$ are $2$-functors, $\mathsf{2Nat}$. Moreover, these are now categories, having two different  notions of sameness: isomorphism and equivalences. This leads  to the consideration of notions such as the following:

**Definition.** An **oplax biadjunction** is a pair $L,R\colon\mathcal{C}\rightleftarrows\mathcal{D}$ of lax functors such that, for each bicategory $\mathcal{K}$, we have a pseudonatural equivalence of categories
$$
\mathsf{OplaxNat}(L\circ F,G)
\overset{\mathrm{e.q.}}{\cong}
\mathsf{OplaxNat}(F,R\circ G),
$$
i.e. such that the pseudobifunctors $\mathsf{OplaxNat}(L\circ(-),-)$ and $\mathsf{OplaxNat}(-,R\circ(-))$ are pseudonaturally equivalent as objects of $\mathsf{PseudoFun}(\mathcal{K},\mathcal{C})^\mathsf{op}\times\mathsf{PseudoFun}(\mathcal{K},\mathcal{D})$.

This leads to a total of eight different notions of $2$-dimensional adjunctions: "lax biadjunction", "oplax bi", "lax", "oplax", "pseudo bi", "pseudo", "$2$-", and "$2$-bi".

**Question:**  How are these definitions related to the ones involving co/units (as defined in e.g.  Section 2 of [[Gurski]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0979)) and those involving isomorphisms/equivalences of $\mathsf{Hom}$-categories (as in e.g. Chapter 9 of [[Fiore]](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408298))?